# Finding Cumulative distribution and density

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $U,V$ be random numbers chosen independently from the interval [0,1]. Find the cumulative distribution and density for the the random variables:

$$Y=max(U,V)$$
and
$$Y=min(U,V)$$

I am not sure how to go about this with the max and min terms. I have the solutions to these but am not sure how they got to them or even where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$Pr(\max(U,V) \le t) = Pr(U \le t, V \le t)$$

$$Pr(\min(U,V) \le t) = 1- Pr(\min(U,V) > t)$$

Comment: I get this but the answer for the first one is $F(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=2x$ on [0,1]. how did they get to that? why $x^2$ and not something else?

Comment: You use that $F_U(x) = F_V(x) = x$ on $(0,1)$. The $x^2$ comes from the fact that $U$ and $V$ are independent

Comment: Okay. So I think that makes sense to me but then the Min is $F(x)=2x-x^2$. This is because $F_U(x)+F_V(x)=2x$?

Comment: Are you able to simplify $Pr(\min(U,V) > t)$?